# No longer able to visit, push or pull or get any response from GitHub

Tags: networking, dns, dhcp, github

From one moment to the other without changing anything in my network or PC, I suddenly can no longer visit `github.com`, and can no longer pull/push my repositories.

Everything else works perfeclty fine. (Other websites, other Services and so on)

I've tried to acces GitHub from other devices in the same network which worked just fine.

When I ping GitHub the request goes out to the correct IP adress but I don't recieve any response.

I've also tried the following commands `ipconfig /flushdns /registerdns /release` and `/renew` which all didn't work either.

A reboot of the system and router wasn't able to resolve the problem either.

I'm at a loss. How is it possible that my PC connects to the correct IP when pinging GitHub and that other devices from the same network work fine?

Comment: Can you compare the output of PowerShell `Find-NetRoute -RemoteIPAddress <github_ip>` on both computers?

Comment: Turns out, that now, it now longer works on any device (I'm sure it did before, I've checked several times). I've called my ISP and they mentioned they currently have problems with certain websites not being accessible. So I hope it's a problem on their end.

Comment: What country are you located in?

Comment: I am living in Switzerland

Comment: have you tried `curl` and another browser? and maybe with a different dns server?

Comment: Yes, I have tried those options aswell. Still waiting to hear back from my ISP.

Comment: Use a different DNS provider like 1.1.1.1 (or something equivalent)

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because OP indicates it is an ISP-caused issue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out that it was a problem by my ISP.

Thank you for your help.